# Doctrine - add custom info to column entity

Tags: doctrine

I have an entity (managed with Doctrine) that is the result of an import of a CSV file; there is a one-to-one correspondence between the CSV column and the table column.
How can I add the name of CSV column to the column definition ?

Now I have used the comment option

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, options={"comment":"Stato"))
```

But I think there is a better way.
Please note that I am now using PHP 7.4 (without attributes) but I will upgrade soon to PHP version 8.

Thanks in advance